# Unable to set config file in nestjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

I have created my .env file outside my src folder in a config folder and i am trying to load that in my main.ts file. It always gives me undefined or NAN.

Where am i going wrong?

GitHub Repo : https://github.com/richakhetan/task-manager-nest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install dotenv `npm i dotenv` and update the main.ts file:

```js
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as path from 'path';

async function bootstrap() {
  dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../config/dev.env') });
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  console.log(process.env.PORT);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

Comment: Not working... (node:18404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at bootstrap (C:\Courses\Node JS\Project\task-manager-nest\dist\main.js:9:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Courses\Node JS\Project\task-manager-nest\dist\main.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)

Comment: You have to import the 'path' module

Comment: const config = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync("C:/Courses/Node JS/Project/task-manager-nest/src/config/dev.env"));
This worked for me but is it a good practice to use read FileSync

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're never loading the `.env` file into your `process.env` the [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package does this with the `config()` method, but you'll need to provide a path to it, as you don't have `.env` in the root, or named as `.env`. It looks like the [`config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) package you're using doesn't support `.env` file formats, so you should be using something like `.json` or [anything else supported by config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed env file outside of src folder and created config module and service.

ConfigService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import * as path from 'path';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    static constants(){
        const baseDir = path.join(__dirname, '../../dev.env');
        const config = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(baseDir));
        return {
            port: config.PORT,
            mongoConnectionString: config.MONGODB_CONNECT,
            jwtSecret: config.SECRETKEY,
            sessionTime: config.SESSIONTIME
        }
    }

}
```

ConfigModule.ts

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [ConfigService],
  exports: [ConfigService]
})
export class ConfigModule {
}
```

and in order to use values using below code

```
ConfigService.constants().port
```

Detailed code available in repository